# Bash / Regex Parsing only Domain Names In File containing both Domans and Email Addresses

Tags: regex, bash, grep

so I'm using a very simple expression to parse a text file but I'm running into a problem where domains contained within email addresses also in the same text file are matching the expression.  To be clear I only want to return domain addresses.

Sample

```
john3525@aol.com
brenda392@yahoo.com
xyx.net
boxers.on.ca
helloworlds.co.uk

grep -E -o "\b[A-Za-z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b" file.txt > file2.txt
```

would return all of the above in the sample where I only want to return

```
xyx.net
boxers.on.ca
helloworlds.co.uk
```

I am thinking I need to be much more specific about the validation Or use some kind of if or case test to validate.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

if your file contains **only** domain and email addr, try this line:

```
grep -v '@' file
```

test with your example:

```
kent$  echo "john3525@aol.com
brenda392@yahoo.com
xyx.net
boxers.on.ca
helloworlds.co.uk"|grep -v '@'
xyx.net
boxers.on.ca
helloworlds.co.uk
```